# ObservableCollection<MyModel> doesn't see property

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, maui

One of the properties of my model that I use in a `CollectionView` in my .NET MAUI app is a class. It looks like this:

```
public MyModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Vehicle Car { get; set; } = new Vehicle();
}
```

My view model looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   ObservableCollection<MyModel> data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

   public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Data
   {
      get => data;
      set
      {
         if(data == value)
            return;

         data = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

In my collection view, when I try to access one of the properties of the `Car` property which is a `Vehicle` object, I get an error that tells me that the property is not found.

```
<CollectionView
   Source={Binding Data}>
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout>
            <Label
               Text={Binding Car.Make} />
         </StackLayout>
      <DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: you haven't shown us the code for `Vehicle`.  Is `Make` a **public property**?

Comment: It’s a super simple class. Just Make, model and year. String, string and int respectively.

Comment: Yes, they’re all public properties

Comment: please post the code so we can see.  Are you able to bind to `Name`?  And is the error you get a compile error or a runtime exception?

Comment: Shouldn’t the binding be in quotes?

Comment: eg. Text="{Binding Car.Make}" instead of Text={Binding Car.Make}

Comment: Sorry, that’s my typo and sloppiness. In the actual code, it’s in quotes.

Comment: do you have a `DataContext` set in your XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code,I created a demo,  and it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<MyModel> data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Data
    {
        get => data;
        set
        {
            if (data == value)
                return;

            data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel() {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

        Data.Add(new MyModel { Name ="model_1", Car= new Vehicle {Make="Make1" } });
        Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_2", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make2" } });
        Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_3", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make3" } });
        Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_4", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make4" } });

    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Vehicle.cs

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCollectionApp.MainPage"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiCollectionApp"
             >

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


   <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{ Binding Data}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Car.Make}" />

                </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

I tested your demo, there are some problems with your code.

1.define `Drivers` as follows:

```
   public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();
```

Not：

```
public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers = new();
```

2.we should initialize the data in the constructor of `MainPageViewModel` ,so we can define `MainPageViewModel.cs` as follows:

```
   public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers = new();

    public ObservableCollection<Driver> Drivers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Driver>();

    public MainPageViewModel() {

        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var car = new Vehicle
        {
            Make = "Subaru",
            Model = "Outback",
            Year = 2019
        };
        var driver = new Driver
        {
            Name = "John Smith",
            Car = car
        };
        Drivers.Add(driver);

        car = new Vehicle
        {
            Make = "Infiniti",
            Model = "Q80",
            Year = 2014
        };
        driver = new Driver
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Car = car
        };
        Drivers.Add(driver);

        car = new Vehicle
        {
            Make = "BMW",
            Model = "535i",
            Year = 2011
        };
        driver = new Driver
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Car = car
        };
        Drivers.Add(driver);
    }
}
```

At the same time, remove code `_vm.Init();` in method `OnAppearing()`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    //_vm.Init();
}
```

3.add `x:DataType` in the`VerticalStackLayout` of `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
           <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <VerticalStackLayout x:DataType="local:Driver">
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        TextColor="Black"/>
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Car.Make}"
                        TextColor="Black"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Besides,add following code on the root of `MainPage.xaml`:

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
```

Comment: Created a sample project and placed it in a GitHub repo. I can't even get this project to build! What am I doing wrong? Here's the repo: https://github.com/imsam67/maui-collectionview

Comment: Hi @Sam,I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part at the bottom of my reply.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may be having an issue determining what the data type is for the items bound to the data template.

You may need to set x:DataType for your `DataTemplate` to `MyModel` so that it knows which properties are available.

It would look something like: `<DataTemplate x:DataType="MyModel">`

See your modified code:

```
<CollectionView
   Source="{Binding Data}">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="declaredNamespace:MyModel">
         <StackLayout>
            <Label
               Text="{Binding Car.Make}" />
         </StackLayout>
      <DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

If it continues to show you the error, you may need to clean and rebuild the solution so that the necessary files and references can be generated. Other than that, it would probably be your `Vehicle` class is actually missing the property, or that property isn't defined properly, but we can't see that code.

Comment: Pushed a sample project to a public repo. I can't even get the project to compile. Here's the repo URL: https://github.com/imsam67/maui-collectionview